# Angular validators e Angular forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular

quando o usuario clicar em "selecionar" acontece  esse metodo,

```
<div  class="card-footer"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" 
(click)="selecionarCartao(responseData[0])">Selecionar</button>
</div>

selecionarCartao(cartao) {
this.dadosCC.get('cardToken').setValue(cartao.token)
}


this.dadosCC = this.fb.group({
  parcelas: [1, Validators.required],
  digiNumero: [null, Validators.required],
  digiNome: [null, Validators.required],
  digiMes: [null, Validators.required],
  digiAno: [null, Validators.required],
  digiCVV: [null, Validators.required],
  valor: [this.cartS.cart.valorTotal || null, Validators.required],
  cpfInput: [this.userS.user.cpf],
  cardToken:[this.cardToken || null, Validators.required],
  });
```

**Codigo html digiNumero**

```
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="ncartao">Número do cartão <span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
<input name="card-number" maxlength="19"  #cardNumber formControlName="digiNumero" 
id="ncartao" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6  " >
</div>
```

**Codigo html digiNome**

```
<label for="nomeimpresso">Nome <b>impresso</b> no cartão<span class="text-danger"> * 
</span></label>
<input #nomeImpresso formControlName="digiNome"  name="holder-name" 
id="nomeimpresso" class="form-control col-lg-6" type="text" >
```

O valor do meu form "cardToken" é atualizado de acordo com o "cartao.token
quando o cliente clicasse nele eu queria que os inputs "numero de cartao", nome impresso, validade e ano fossem desabilitados, só ficasse o codigo de segurança para o cliente digitar
eu só iria enviar o token do cartao e o cvv para o back end
[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Comment: Amigo, desculpa, não entendi qual é o problema que estás tentando resolver. Há algum erro ou comportamento inesperado?

Comment: Então, eu queria saber se na função selecionarCartao, caso venha algo no cartao.token os inputs  "nome impresso, numero do cartao, validade, ano " fossem desabilitados

Comment: acho que pra tu fazer o que tá querendo, vai ter que usar o método `valueChanges`, dessa forma:
`this.form.get("campo").valueChanges.subscribe(valor => {
   console.log('campo mudou')
   console.log("valor do campo", valor)
})`